Start a separate process in Powershell, redirect all output, and later kill it
I'm trying to write what seems like an ostensibly simple Powershell script: Start up a web server (Storybook), wait until it is responding, run some Playwright tests against it, kill that web server again. It needs to run on both Windows and Linux machines, and will be used in both local development and on CI. Here is what I have:
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh

Function Test-StoryBookConnection() {
  Try {
    $SC = (Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri "http://localhost:6006/" ).StatusCode
  }
  catch {
    $SC = $error
  }
  return $SC
}

($storybookProcess = Start-Process npx -PassThru -ArgumentList "storybook", "dev", "-p", "6006", "--ci", "--quiet") *>$null

Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting –Action { $storybookProcess | ForEach-Object { $_.Kill() } }

$i = 1
Do {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
  $SC = Test-StoryBookConnection
  $i++
} Until( $SC -eq 200 -or $i -gt 20 )

npm run test:visual

Stop-Process -Force -Id $storybookProcess.Id

This mostly works - it does start the server, wait until it responds 200 and then run the tests which pass. But two necessary features aren't working, despite trying many different solutions from many different articles. Namely:

Output from the web server started by Start-Process is still being sent to the console, despite using *> $null. This will make the output very difficult to read in CI reports.
The web server process does not stop at the end of the script, despite using both Stop-Process with -Force and (in the Register-EngineEvent check) Kill() on the process(es). If the process is not killed, it will cause a lot of problems in CI.

I've tried so many things at this point. It seems like there are loads of different suggestions for how to achieve these two features in Powershell syntax and they may have worked for some version of Powershell on some platform in the past, but they aren't working for modern pwsh / Powershell Core running on Ubuntu.
